# Creating Session ID Buckets

Tags: sql, teradata, partitioning

I am trying to create a session_id column that groups a bunch of sessions into buckets based on if there has been a 30 minute gap...

| ID | Session_TM |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 00:15:12 |
| 001 | 00:17:17 |
| 001 | 01:00:00 |
| 001 | 01:55:00 |
| 001 | 01:58:22 |
| 002 | 02:10:10 |
| 002 | 02:15:12 |
| 002 | 04:15:01 |

The result I am after is something that would look like..

| ID | Session_TM_Min | Session_TM_Max | Session_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 00:15:12 | 00:17:17 | 1 |
| 001 | 01:00:00 | 01:00:00 | 2 |
| 001 | 01:55:00 | 01:58:00 | 3 |
| 002 | 02:10:10 | 02:15:12 | 1 |
| 001 | 04:15:01 | 04:15:01 | 2 |

I've tried Row_Number() over Partition but nothing seems to get me the right results.

Any support and ideas appreciated

Comment: I've added a possible answer, but in future you should consider providing more details of exactly what you've already tried (showing us the code) and why it didn't work, with any errors or the unexpected output.

Comment: Teradata has a `SESSIONIZE` function for this. https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Database-Analytic-Functions/Path-and-Pattern-Analysis-Functions/Sessionize

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data (but incrementing all the times by one hour, as otherwise this causes an issue with checking for something up to 30 minutes before 00:15:12*):

```
create table #sessions
(
    ID varchar(3),
    Session_TM time
)

insert into #sessions values
('001','01:15:12'),
('001','01:17:17'),
('001','02:00:00'),
('001','02:55:00'),
('001','02:58:22'),
('002','03:10:10'),
('002','03:15:12'),
('002','05:15:01')
```

You can use a CTE to establish the groups, then some grouping and a window function to return your desired otuput:

```
with myGroups as
(
    select
        *,
        count(newGroup) over (order by Session_TM rows unbounded preceding) as groupNum
    from
    (
        select
            *,
            case when lag(Session_TM,1,'') over (partition by ID order by Session_TM) < dateadd(minute, -30, Session_TM) then 1 end as newGroup
        from #sessions
    ) s
)
select
    g.ID,
    min(g.Session_TM) as Session_TM_Min,
    max(g.Session_TM) as Session_TM_Max,
    row_number() over (partition by g.ID order by g.groupNum) as Session_ID
from myGroups g
group by g.ID,
         g.groupNum
```

Results:

| ID | Session_TM_Min | Session_TM_Max | Session_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:15:12 | 00:17:17 | 1 |
| 1 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 00:55:00 | 00:58:22 | 3 |
| 2 | 00:10:10 | 00:15:12 | 1 |
| 2 | 00:15:01 | 00:15:01 | 2 |

*If you need to handle times within 30 minutes of midnight, then I would suggest you need to be storing a datetime, not just a time value. But if you really wanted to do this without datetimes, then you could add to the case statement to also flag any time of 00:30:00 or earlier as being a "new group" explicitly.